# Is there a way to deploy Azure Data factory other than using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I want to deploy my azure data factory using Azure DevOps. I have worked with the deployment using ARM templates with resource group deployment tasks during the release pipeline, but I want to know any other way for the ADF deployment apart from ARM templates?

The reason being that ARM templates deploy everything but I have lot of sample pipelines in my DEV environment which cant be deployed in other QA or Production. But ARM templates are restricting me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/data_factory.html)
2. [Azure Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/?view=azps-3.5.0)
3. [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/azure_rm_resource_module.html#azure-rm-resource-module) resource module \ Azure Cli \ SDK's \ Rest Api

Last one requires bit of creativity, you'd have to construct API call on your own.

Comment: Actually i need solution using Azure devops only.Can you help me with some information how do i use these in azure devops?

Comment: easily googleable, you have built-in steps for terraform and azure powershell as well

Comment: Isn't this selective deployment possible using ARM templates only? any task which uses ARM templates and can utilize them for the selective deployment?Just in case.

Comment: I have no idea what a "selective deployment" is. can you clarify please?

Comment: The ARM template as you know contains the information regarding all the pipelines, dataset, workflows of the Azure data Factory. So when we deploy using ARMtemplate, it will deploy all these resources whether or not required in production. Selective deployment here means that we kind of choose which are to be deployed and which are not to be deployed. Why to deploy the whole data factory again and again if not required to do so? Tha is what i mean here.

Comment: you can remove things from the template that you do not want to deploy or use the condition property and if() statements to optionally deploy things within a single template - is that what you mean?

Comment: Ansible Link is broken now :) Please update.

Comment: you can use google and you can edit this answer. i have several thousand answers on this site. i cant keep all of them updated